# .htaccess rewrite full domain name

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, dns, url-rewriting

Are there anyway to make a user get to download thefile by let them type:`download.mywebsite.com/thefile` 
in the browser address while the "download.mywebsite.com/thefile" does not exist but the "www.mywebsite.com/thefile" does.

I've got nearly zero knowledge with .htaccess and mod_rewrite engine. I hope my question is clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IF you own `mywebsite.com` then yes you could, you would have to place a `ServerAlias` in your root `httpd.conf` directive then use mod_rewrite to re-write all requests for `download.mywebsite.com/thefile` to `www.mywebsite.com/thefile` but the `mod_rewrit`e would not know if a file exists or not in advance.

Another way to do it would be implement a custom error document for a 404 handler which redirects a user to a suggested URL.

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^/download/(.*)$ http://download.mywebsite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

You need to set up your web server to listen for sub-domains as well